# Can I sync with my iOS4 device such as iPhone 4 and iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad

If Ubuntu can't do this natively, are there any workarounds?

Comment: Using what? With banshee? What you plan to sync?

Answer (score 6):

1. Open up the Synaptic Package Manager
2. Go to the Repositories (Under Settings)
3. Add this source -  ppa:pmcenery/ppa
4. Click Close and then click the 'Reload' button at the top left of the Synaptic Package Manager
5. After it's finished reloading search for - libimobiledevice1
6. You will see two package in the list, install both of them
7. Now click the 'mark all upgrades' button and click 'mark' when the popup appears then click the 'Apply' button of the Synaptic Package Manager.
8. The software packages will then be downloaded and installed.
9. Restart your computer and login back in.
10. The 1st time you connect you ipod/iphone/ipad with rhythmbox open it will unmount. Just close rhythmbox then disconnect and reconnect you ipod/iphone. You should now see your ipod/iphone/ipad listed under Devices in rhythmbox.

Notes -  Always best not to have rhythmbox open before you connect your ipod/iphone/ipad
Rhythmbox is only supported, rhythmbox may say the songs are transferred but the 'Sync in Progress' is usually shown on the ipod/iphone/ipad after so just wait till you no longer see this displayed.

For a more detailed how to, see hee - http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=53489

Comment: it is not required to restart after the installation, everything working on ubuntu 10.10 Linux 2.6.35-28-generic

Comment: "Music/Video Synchronization doesn't currently work for devices with DBVersion > 4 (run "ideviceinfo -q com.apple.mobile.iTunes -k DBVersion" to check your DBVersion run). It may be moving the files but it isn't updating the DB correctly." See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/87586/54949)

Answer (score 2):

> Lucid natively supports both iPhone
>   and iPod Touch 1G, 2G, 3G and 3GS
>   models (iPad should also work) running
>   up to firmware 4.0 without the need to
>   jailbreak.

If you want to use you iPhone for USB tethering check out this [blog post](http://www.mexlinux.com/how-to-tether-iphone-on-ubuntu-via-usb/).

More information can be found at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PortableDevices/iPhone.

Comment: newer versions libimobiledevice work

Answer (score 2):

I have actually had success in syncing my iPhone 4 (iOS 4.2.8), with Rhythmbox on Ubuntu 11.04. I still however, cannot get Banshee to work (and that is by far my favorite player, it feels MUCH more polished). Read the all the steps before you begin, some steps are more than one procedure and require information to complete. Here is what I did:

1. Installed all the libraries/applications indicated above (libmobiledevice, iFuse etc).
2. Then, as you are Jailbroken, Download iFile (easy) or SSH to your iphone (pain) and locate and edit  /System/Library/Lockdown/Checkpoint.xml. Find the DBVersion key, and change its value from 5 to 4. Save and reboot your iPhone.
3. Then, you can use this page (http://ihash.marcansoft.com/) to generate a HashInfo file for your device and manually copy it to your phone. There will be instructions on that link above, that tell you where the hashinfo file goes after you create it. Note* You will need to have your UIDID.

It is a PAIN to get the UIDID from your phone unless you have iTunes, obviously we are using Linux (no iTunes), BUT there is a simple command to find it on your Linux machine: in the terminal with your iPhone connected, type:

```
lsusb -v
```

It prints a TON of text that seems to repeat, but keep scrolling down until you see "iSerial: (40 letters and numbers in random sequence)" Copy that serial/uidid info into the website hashgenerator above, and copy it to itunes_control/Device as per the sites' instructions. After all is done above, open Rythmbox, and you're set!

If it still does not work, I can try to clarify the steps further. It was a ROYAL PAIN for me to hunt these down until it worked, but it works flawlessly in Rhythmbox. (Banshee would be better.... but beggars cant be choosers! :)

Answer (score 1):

Banshee and Rhythmbow don't work with an iPad 2 at this point. I did not try the step above though ( https://askubuntu.com/a/62479/35622 ).

But it is possible to copy mp3 (m4b not supported, don't know about other formats) to Good Reader with Ubuntu and play them.

AVPlayerHD is even better ( http://itunes.apple.com/en/app/avplayerhd/id407976815?mt=8 ), this supported m4b and it is easy to copy files with file browser or via wifi.

Comment: Yep that's one workaround at the last resort. There are many apps on iOS that allow to connect from a computer and transmit files. One I have is called "Stash" (it also lets you put a password and multiple users/collections). I guess the trick then is to use one of those apps that has "Open in..." options. Then you could use "Open in iBooks" to get your PDF files there. I don't know if you can use "Open in" to transfer music and video to the native iOS apps though :/

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy way to connect an Iphone or Ipad to Ubuntu:

- Open up the Synaptic Package Manager
- Go to the Repositories (Under Settings)
- Add this source - `ppa:pmcenery/ppa`
- Click 'Close', and then click the 'Reload' button at the top left of the Synaptic Package Manager