# How can I sync an iPad?

Tags: sync, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I sync with my iPhone 4 and iPad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994/can-i-sync-with-my-iphone-4-and-ipad)

I am mainly curious about my Music and Contacts...

Comment: No, Banshee nor Rhytmbox work with an iPad 2 at this point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Banshee](http://banshee.fm/). It will be default in 11.04, but for now you can see [how to install](http://banshee.fm/download/) it from their website.