# Update (manage) podcasts on iPhone4

Tags: iphone, podcast

Is there a way I can update (manage) podcasts on my iPhone4 from Ubuntu?

What I especially want to do is:
- check if new episodes of podcasts are available
- download new episodes

Answer (score 2):

### GPodder

Use GPodder to manage your podcasts.

[image]

Depending on what sort of IPhone4 you have - use this [Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994/can-i-sync-with-my-iphone-4-and-ipad) to sync the downloaded podcasts.

### HPodder

HPodder is a command line tool to manage podcasts - if you couple this with a crontab entry, it will download your podcasts on any crontab schedule you setup