# After sync, music still cannot be located on iOS 5 device, fix?

Tags: banshee, sync, iphone

First question of many I am sure.  I was able to mount my iPhone 4 w/ recently upgraded iOS 5.  Tried to sync some music w/ Banshee, it went onto the iPhone, but it won't show up in the 'Music' app the device.  It is definitely on the phone, in the correct directory.  Running 11.10.

Does anybody have any solutions or advice?

Comment: Banshee hasnt quite caught up with iOS5 yet.  This is one of those bugs that they have to update their iPod integration with first.

Answer (score 4):

Music/Video Synchronization doesn't currently work for devices with DBVersion > 4 (run "ideviceinfo -q com.apple.mobile.iTunes -k DBVersion" to check your DBVersion run). 
It may be moving the files but it isn't updating the DB correctly.

You can keep yourself updated here: http://www.libimobiledevice.org/

or here as well: http://gtkpod.org/wiki/Libgpod

Answer (score 0):

Where does banshee put the files?

With this info it should be possible to load the music on with banshee, then movet the music to an approiate directory for using a program like mewseek (Cydia) that can add files to the music app.

I feel like this is faster than using say ftp with mewseek or similar programs.