# How to sync iPhone in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, sync, music, iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I sync with my iPhone 4 and iPad?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994/can-i-sync-with-my-iphone-4-and-ipad)

How i'm looking for a simple and convenient way of transferring music from my Ubuntu 12.04 machine with my iPhone 4. I'v read that this is now possible in 12.04 but I have yet to see any evidence.

Each time I sync my iPhone with ryhthmbox it appears to sync but the music is never on my iPhone.

Thanks in advance for any help.