# Can't copy my music from Rhythmbox to my iPhone

Tags: rhythmbox, iphone

I am using Rhythmbox (2.96) using a iphone 4.2.1. I installed the libimobiledevice

```
sudo apt-get install ipheth-utils libimobiledevice-dev libimobiledevice-utils
```

But when i drag and drop a `.mp3` file on my iphone icon via rhythmbox.
 
it won't start working.

Comment: Have you looked at any of these questions? http://askubuntu.com/q/27141/10698
http://askubuntu.com/q/994/10698

Comment: It doesn't work for me either.  Never got an answer when I asked. http://askubuntu.com/questions/567437/rhythmbox-file-transfer-to-ipod

Answer (score 2):

Try copying music from Nautilus (the file browser) to the iPhone instead, treating the iPhone like a drive.

<sup>If that doesn't work, please *edit your question* to update it with more information.</sup>